# Monotonicity of sequence of functions - Dini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

To apply Dini's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) we must have monotonicity, i.e. either $f_k(x)\leq f_{k+1}(x)$ or $f_k(x)\geq f_{k+1}(x)$ for all $x$ and from a $k$ onwards.

---

Let's assume we have a nice sequence of functions such that we are able to interpret it as a two dimensional function $f(x,k)$ which is differentiable w.r.t. $k$. Think of something like $f_k(x)= \frac{1}{k}+x.$

Is it legit to show the required monotonicity by means of the derivative $D_kf(x,k)$?

In the case of $f_k(x)= \frac{1}{k}+x$, we get $D_kf(x,k)=-\frac{1}{k^2}<0$. So for an arbitrary but fixed $x$ incrementing the index of the sequence of functions decreases $f_k(x)$. So we have monotonicity.

I see nothing wrong with that. However, it seems strange because it would save a lot of work.

Comment: The theorem that you mention for proving monotonicity is true only in intervals. When k is an integer it's not true.

Comment: @Philipp There is no problem with anything you are saying. If you have such a dependence on $k$ and the derivative has a constant sign, then you have proven monotonicity. Yes, it saves a lot of work, when available.

Comment: @LawrenceMano, in the sense that $f_k$ is a sequence of functions $k$ is an integer. But nothing prevents you from "redefining" the setting. If you can prove a statement for each $k\in\mathbb{R}$ then it certainly holds for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @plop, what if the functions of the sequence are monotone on intervals. Say $f_k:[a,c]\to\mathbb{R}$ and for all $k$ we have that $f_k$ is monotone increasing on $[a,b]$ and monotone decreasing on $[b,c]$, where $a<b<c$. Am I allowed to apply Dini's theorem on each interval and conclude uniform convergence (if the other assumptions of Dini's theorem are satisfied)?

Comment: You can apply Dini's theorem whenever its hypotheses are satisfied. You wouldn't be able to apply it directly on $[a,c]$. That, however, doesn't stop you from concluding, from the uniform convergence on $[a,b]$ and the uniform convergence on $[b,c]$ to conclude the uniform convergence on $[a,c]$.

Comment: @plop, ahh ok I see it. Thanks for your feedback :)